# How do I select files with specific words in their content from a folder?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to filter files having any of the words January or February in their content.

```cs
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Desktop\NewFolder\" -Recurse -Filter "*Support*" 
$count = 0
$p = 'january', 'February'

foreach ($file in $files){
    if((Get-Content $file.FullName) | Select-String -Pattern '^%january%'){
        Write-Host "File found"
        #write-host $file.FullName
        $count++
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "File NOt found"
    }
}

Write-Host $count
```

Currently I am just getting "File NOt found" even though the file exists

Comment: I am not sure that if statement will do anything. Never seen one written like that.

Comment: @Backin It would be evaluated as a truthy falsy. If select-string returned any non-error response it would be true. However the regex is likely flawed as they appear to be using percent as a wildcard which it is not.

Comment: @Matt - Would it be treated the same as something like this `If($Test_Var){ for true }Else{ for false }` which is something I have used to see if a variable is empty/null

Comment: @Backin Similar yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might simply be your regex string although improvement could still be made as a whole. The percent sign is not a wildcard character in regex also are you expecting the month to appear at the start of a line? That is what the anchor `^` represents.

So likely your files do not have the string %January% at the start of any line. Like I mentioned earlier I don't think that is what you wanted.

So lets find all the files you want and filter those files based on the presence of either of the works in `$p` (like in your example above)

```
$p ='january','February'
$regexPattern = ($p | ForEach-Object{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp\" -filter "*.txt"
$files | Where-Object{Select-String -Path $_.Fullname -Pattern $regexPattern}
```

That will spit out any file objects that have the work January or February in them anywhere in the line.

`$regexPattern` would end up being a pipeline delimited string of the words in `$p`. `[regex]::Escape()` is a good way to avoid special regex characters in your strings especially if you are just using examples.

You would of course need to change the -Path and -Filter accordingly as well as including -Recurse if the situation calls for it.

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for understanding what i am trying to do . But the code that you shared does not give any output with file name though the files are there with those search words.

Comment: @User It works in my test environment. Did you change the path and filter accordingly for `Get-ChildItem`? You do not show and sample of target file although it should not matter since my code should pull for a file with either of those months in it. I will double check its does what it did on my other computer.

Comment: I got it. Thanks @Matt for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
Select-String -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\NewFolder\*Support*" -Pattern January,february
```

or (if you need to recurse the path)

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\Desktop\NewFolder" -Include *Support* -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern January,february
```

should get you what you want?
(Select-String also has a `-CaseSensitive` switch if you should need that)